# knockoutjs template jquery autocomplete - how to populate inputs on autocomplete select?

Tags: jquery-ui, knockout.js

I want to populate multiple inputs inside a template after select of an autocomplete item.  I'm following http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/MJQ6g/ but not sure how to apply this to multiple inputs.

Model:

```
<script>
        var ContactModel = function (contactsInfo) {
            var self = this;
            self.Company = ko.observable();
            self.ContactsInformation = contactsInfo;
            self.Name = ko.observable();
        };

        var ContactsInformationModel = function () {
            var self = this;
            self.Address1 = ko.observable();
        };

     var viewModel;

     var ViewModel = function () {
         var self = this;
         self.Contact1 = new ContactModel(new ContactsInformation);
         self.Contact2 = new ContactModel(new ContactsInformation);
     };

     $(function () {
         viewModel = new ViewModel();
         ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
     });

    function getContacts(searchTerm, sourceArray) {
        $.getJSON("web_service_uri" + searchTerm, function (data) {
            var mapped = $.map(data, function (item) {
                return {
                    label: item.Name,
                    value: item
                };
            });
            return sourceArray(mapped);
        });
    }
</script>
```

Template:

```
<script type="text/html" id="contact-template">                 
     <div>   
            Name
              <input data-bind="uniqueName: true,
                jqAuto: { autoFocus: true, html: true }, 
                jqAutoSource: $root.Contacts, 
                jqAutoQuery: getContacts, 
                jqAutoValue: Name, 
                jqAutoSourceLabel: 'label', 
                jqAutoSourceInputValue: 'value', 
                jqAutoSourceValue: 'label'"
                class="name" />    
     </div>
    <div>
        Company
        <input data-bind="value: Company, uniqueName: true" class="company" />
    </div>
    <div>
        Address
        <input data-bind="value: ContactsInformation.Address1, uniqueName: true" class="address1" />
    </div>        
</script>
```

Html:

```
<div data-bind="template: { name: 'contact-template', data: Contact1 }">
        </div>
<hr/>
        <div data-bind="template: { name: 'contact-template', data: Contact2 }">
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you leave out the `jqAutoSourceValue` option from your `data-bind`, then it will set the value equal to the actual object.  Then, you can read properties off of that object.

Usually, you would have an observable like: `mySelectedPerson` and then bind a section (possibly with the `with` binding) against it and access the individual properties/observables off of that object.

Here is the sample modified to leave out the `jqAutoSourceValue` option, bind `jqAutoValue` against an observable called `mySelectedPerson` and use the `with` binding to display some properties from the selected object.  http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/YHvyL/

Comment: Thanks RP.  How would I do this if I'm using a template?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to do this multiple times for each line in an array or just that you want to do it in a template?

Comment: Yes I want to do this multiple times for each line in an array. Sorry I should have done this before http://jsfiddle.net/Km52a/3/. In my example, if I use "with" in the template it doesn't render in jsfiddle.

Comment: @dm80 - you will want to remove the reference to jQuery Templates.  It is no longer necessary to use jQuery Templates as of KO 2.0 and the control-flow bindings (`if`/`with`, etc.) will not work with jQuery Templates.  Here it is without that resource: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/Km52a/4/.  Now, you will want to bind each line to their own selected item observable rather than the same one at the $root level.

Comment: Really appreciate your help RP but I just can't seem to get it. If the triggering jqAuto input is inside the template then what do I need to set the jqAutoValue to?